# Can't get Client IP Address connected through a proxy using request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for");

Tags: java, client, ip-address

I tried to get client ip address connected server through a proxy by the following:

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println("x-forwarded-for : "+request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for"));

out.println("remote : "+request.getRemoteAddr());
```

But I get always null from `getHeader("x-forwarded-for")` method.

I get only remote address by `getRemoteAddr()`.

But I tried spoofer firefox plugin and it works.

Anybody knows the solution? Thanks.

Comment: is it case sensitive? Try X-Forwarded-For, and try printing out all the header names so you can see exactly what you are receiving.

Comment: ... and you can also use ngrep to find out, what really comes to your server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if that proxy server indeed add the 'x-forwarded-for' header to the request. A proxy server is not obligatory to do so.

Comment: Headers are not case sensitive. Hence findout what ries is saying